# Button doesn't "pop-up" => transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm coding this WebPage rn and for some reason my button won't transform, as in get bigger once I hover over it. Everything else in the class works, like the box-shadow for example.

Here is my code for the button in general:

```
.btn{
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  width: 30rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(28,26,26);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 167, 2)0%, rgb(255, 255, 255)100%);
}
```

and here is the code for when I hover over it:

```
.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0.3rem 1.3rem 0 rgba(255, 167, 2);
  transition: transform 150ms;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML also that you are using? The CSS worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

no thing wrong but the values of the transform and the transition

```
transform: scale(1.03);
```

this will increase the width and the height 3% and this is very small you will never notice
and the transition is working but again 150ms is small increase it a bit

```css
        .btn {
            font-size: 2.3rem;
            width: 30rem;
            padding: 1.5rem;
            border-radius: 0.3rem;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: rgb(28, 26, 26);
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 167, 2)0%, rgb(255, 255, 255)100%);
        }
        
        .btn:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 0.3rem 1.3rem 0 rgba(255, 167, 2);
            transition: transform 1500ms;
            transform: scale(1.5);
        }
```

```html
    <button class='btn'>button</button>
```